# How can I do a rotateX in raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael, transform

My search in the documentation of Raphael.js ends up in `transform` functionality, that [seem] to only support 2D transformation. i.e. translate, rotate, scale.

Now the question is: is there any way to apply (and animate) an element with a 3D transformation. e.g. rotateX. like what we have in CSS3:

```
transform: rotateX(100deg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Raphael only supports rotation in 2D around a given point with the [rotate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.rotate) method.